# kinect not connecting even though powered

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, kinect, ros, openni, lsusb

I'm trying to use a kinect xbox360 with ubuntu 12.04 (and eventually ROS).

The kinect is plugged in and powered on (blinking green light).  When running `lsusb`, I do *not* see the expected three Microsoft devices

`Bus 002 Device 009: ID 045e:02ae Microsoft Corp. 
 Bus 002 Device 008: ID 045e:02ad Microsoft Corp. 
 Bus 002 Device 007: ID 045e:02b0 Microsoft Corp.`

When running `lsusb -t`, I do see a device, with device ID that changes when plugging in/ unplugging the kinect (I also see a different device ID when plugging in a USB drive to test...).
I thought it might be a permissions issue, so I've added my user name to the "dialout" group `sudo adduser username dialout` and logged out... without a change in behaviour.

Any ideas would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Did you try to run as administrator? check this as well - http://www.instructables.com/id/Hooking-up-a-Kinect-to-your-Computer-Using-Ubuntu/